# Inline elements next to block elements

Tags: html, css

I have a question about inline and block elements. Is it correct to put inline elements on the same level as block elements? Or should I wrap them?

Example:

```
<div class="name">
     <span class="name__text">List name</span>
</div>
<div class="list>
    ...
</div>
```

or without wrapping

```
<span class="name">List name</span>
<div class="list>
    ...
</div>
```

Both examples works well. Does specification say something about that?

Comment: Since it's a valid HTML then there is no issue. All depend on what you want and the layout you want to achieve but both are fine. As a side note, a span can be changed to block element and div to inline using CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as HTML remains valid, both solutions can be used. However, additional wrapping can be usefull later, when You are writing more and more code. First structure allows You to create a simple CSS grid which will help you keep the code clear.

Answer (score 0):

Both are technically correct and will return the same result, but ultimately it comes down to personal preferences and what you're trying to get from it.
FYI, you can also change the inline behavior in order to use it as a block element:

```css
.example {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

span {
  background: red;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.list {
  background: green;
  height: 30px;
}

.example.three span {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example one">
  <div class="name">
     <span class="name__text">List name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example two">
  <span class="name__text">List name</span>
  <div class="list">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example three">
  <span class="name__text">List name</span>
  <div class="list">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```